# mouse press over event and qtabwidget

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

need that when a mouse ( with press button ) is on top of tab, it gets activated.
How is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the [mouseMoveEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) event from the QTabBar.

**Edit: How To**

To intercept it Qt offers you a great functionalities. You can install an event filter on a widget you have created so it will be able to get filtered event of its child widgets. See documentation about the [installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#installEventFilter) function.

Comment: considering i am relatively moderate. How may i do so. Should i create a subclass of qtabbar like the droparea example on the net. suggest. thank you sharing so far.

Comment: You can subclass QTabBar but Qt offers an other simplier solution to get event of child widget: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own EventFilter.

```
// TabBarEventHandler
class TabBarEventHandler : public QObject
{
public:
    explicit TabBarEventHandler( QTabWidget * tabWidget );
    virtual ~TabBarEventHandler();

    void Initialize();

protected:
    QTabWidget  * mTabWidget;

    virtual bool eventFilter( QObject* obj, QEvent* event ) override;
};


// TabBarEventHandler
TabBarEventHandler::TabBarEventHandler( TabBar * tabWidget ) 
    : mTabWidget( tabWidget )
{
}

TabBarEventHandler::~TabBarEventHandler()
{
    mTabWidget->tabBar()->removeEventFilter( this );
}

void TabBarEventHandler::Initialize()
{
    mTabWidget->tabBar()->installEventFilter( this );
}

bool TabBarEventHandler::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << event->type();

    return QObject::eventFilter( obj, event );
}

void TabBarEventHandler::timerEvent(QTimerEvent* event)
{
}
```

And in your widget:

```
MyTabWidget::MyTabWidget( QWidget * parent ) : QTabWidget( parent )
{
    mEventHandler = new TabBarEventHandler( this );
    mEventHandler->Initialize();
}

MyTabWidget::~MyTabWidget()
{
    delete mEventHandler;
}
```

The debug output:

> QEvent::Type(HoverMove) QEvent::Type(HoverMove)
>   QEvent::Type(MouseButtonPress) QEvent::Type(InputMethodQuery)
>   QEvent::Type(InputMethodQuery) QEvent::Type(InputMethodQuery)
>   QEvent::Type(Paint) QEvent::Type(Paint)
>   QEvent::Type(MouseButtonRelease) QEvent::Type(HoverMove)
>   QEvent::Type(HoverMove) QEvent::Type(Leave)